# How does CUDA raytracing match raycasts against vertices stored in the graphics pipeline?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, raytracing

So, I think I understand the basic functionality of cuda, and also how the graphics pipeline works. But what I don't understand is how CUDA raytracing engines combine those two. Since the vertices of a scene are stored in the graphics pipeline via directx or opengl, I can't see how this information can be accessed via the cuda pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't see how this information can be accessed via the cuda pipeline.

First of all, you can write a ray-tracer that doesn't use the graphics pipeline at all, except for final display of the pixels (e.g. glDrawPixels).  An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609830/compiling-cuda-program).

But in general, the sharing of data between OGL/DX and CUDA is facilitated by the [interop APIs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html).  These APIs allow for various kinds of data to be shared between CUDA and OpenGL, including final rendered pixels, geometry data, and textures.  There are plenty of [CUDA sample codes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#graphics) which demonstrate all of these types of data sharing, in both directions, including display of results.